# View.setPadding affects background ShapeDrawable padding

Tags: android, android-view, padding, android-background, android-shapedrawable

I have a custom view with a background drawable.

The drawable has an inside shape with padding. **No padding is applied on the view itself**.

Whenever I set a padding on the view programmatically using [View.setPadding(left,top,right,bottom)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)), the shape padding gets changed too and I honestly cannot figure out why.

The xmls are defined as follows:

**Background drawable**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/radius_large" />
            <solid android:color="@color/yellow" />
            <padding
                    android:left="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:right="@dimen/spacing_large"
                    android:top="@dimen/spacing_medium_to_large"
                    android:bottom="@dimen/spacing_medium_to_large" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

**Custom view extending ConstraintLayout** *(edited)*

The `tools: attrs` on the `<merge>` tag are simply used to render what the outcome will be in the layout preview. 
As you know, `<merge>` is not a viewgroup, so it doesn't allow attrs such as background etc

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:parentTag="androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout"
        tools:background="@drawable/background_start_lesson"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
            ... />

    <ImageView
            ... />

    <TextView
            ... />


</merge>
```

In the constructor of my custom view, I simply set the `R.drawable.background_start_lesson`

And this of course just renders nicely as expected, with large paddings:

[image: Custom view with padding set on the shape]

.....but if I just set the padding of the view itself to 0dp programmatically or via xml *(and it should be already at 0dp, given that I specified none on the view!)*, this is what happens:

[image: Custom view with 0dp padding set programmatically]

In conclusion, **why does setPadding() change the `<shape>` drawable padding and not the padding of the view**?

Comment: the padding amount will sum up. what is the type of your custom view? if you use imageView you won't have this issue.

Comment: @EliasFazel The type of the custom view is ConstraintLayout (you can see it from the tools:parentTag in <merge>). As you can see, it is not summing up